# Custom SSL Certificate with Cloud Front on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront

I am following this video tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbQbwum196g to install a Custom SSL Certificate with Cloud Front on my AWS Server, I followed all steps correctly and everything seems fine even created certificate on zone "us-east-1" (Virginia) as recommended on others posts I read but, I still get same problem, the problem I get is that server refuses Https connection, so every time I try to access https I get this error on browser "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" for this error I can imagine is a permissions problem but, I don't seem to figure out what I am missing, can someone please give me a hand, thanks!

Comment: Have you double check the ports?

Comment: I think so, port 443 is open on EC2 and on cloudfront, but, I am missing some place?

Comment: Hmnn, I see. Sorry but it's really hard to answer by just guessing. Try their support.

Comment: Can you at least tell me what I am suppose to check so, I am sure ports are open? or is there any option I need to tick on Cloudfront Distribution to allow HTTPS? Thanks for trying!

Comment: Or is there a package I have to install that is not mention on tutorial? like openssl or something?

Comment: I notice that I am not using S3 bucket on my Origin Name on Cloud Front because is not mention on tutorial, could that be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: In the post, you mentioned AWS server but here you mention S3 bucket. So which one is your origin? If it is an EC2 instance, then is SSL configured on your instance?

Comment: Yes the origin is EC2 Instance and SSL Certificate is installed on EC2 instance but, the problem is when I put CloudFront to use HTTPS then theme breaks on website (css design).